# calendar javascript starts and ends wrong

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic selection calendar, the problem is that my date array always starts and ends one day before the selected dates, for example, if I select the date October 2 as start and October 7 as Finally, my calendar starts on October 1 and ends on October 6, would you be so kind and tell me what I'm doing wrong

```HTML
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Getting Started with Chart JS with www.chartjs3.com</title>
        <style>
  

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
          }
          .chartMenu {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 40px;
            background: #1A1A1A;
            color: rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
          }
          .chartMenu p {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
          }
          .chartCard {
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc(100vh - 40px);
            background: rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          .chartBox {
            width: 700px;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
            background: white;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div class="chartCard">
          <div class="chartBox">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    
            Start: <input id="start" type="date" min="2021-11-01" max="2021-11-03" value="2021-11-02"> End:<input type="date" id="end" min="2021-11-04" max="2021-11-08" value="2021-11-05">
            <button onclick="filterDate()">Filtrar</button>
            <br>
            <button onclick="resetDate()">Limpiar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    <script src="package/dist/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="package/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="package/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // setup
    
      const dates =['2021-11-01','2021-11-02','2021-11-03','2021-11-04','2021-11-05','2021-11-06', '2021-11-07'];
      const datapoints = [18,12,6,9,12,3,9];

      const convertedDates = dates.map(date => new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0));
      console.log(convertedDates);

    const data = {
      labels: dates,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: datapoints,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: {
              type: 'time',  
              time: {
                unit: 'day'
                }
            },
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );

    function filterDate(){
      const start1 = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
      const start = start1.setHours(0,0,0,0); 
      const end1 = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);
      const end = end1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

      const filterDates = convertedDates.filter(date => date >= start && date <= end)
      myChart.config.data.labels = filterDates;

      const startArray = convertedDates.indexOf(filterDates[0])
      const endArray = convertedDates.indexOf(filterDates[filterDates.length-1])
      console.log(endArray);
      const copyDatapoints = [...datapoints];
      copyDatapoints.splice(endArray + 1, filterDates.length);
      copyDatapoints.splice(0, startArray );
      console.log(copyDatapoints);
      myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = copyDatapoints;
      myChart.update();
    }

    function resetDate(){
      myChart.config.data.labels = convertedDates;
      myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = datapoints;

      myChart.update();
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't go all the way through your code but as I stopped right at your date declarations.  I think it's the way you are creating the dates and GMT is messing with you.

For example

```
const start1 = new Date('2022-11-01');
const start = start1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

If you then print out start which is what you are using you get 1667188800000.  Go to an epoch time converter (https://www.epochconverter.com) and plug that in and you see that it says Oct 31 with some time GMT.